# EXC_BAD_ACCESS When accessing property of custom MKAnnotation in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, swift, exc-bad-access

I have a custom MKAnnotation that holds a model class Poi.

Which i initialise like so

```
let annotation = PoiAnnotation()
annotation.poi = poi
...
```

Then in my calloutAccessoryControlTrapped delegate:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    let annotation = view.annotation as PoiAnnotation

    selectedPoi = annotation.poi
```

At the point i try to access the .poi property of my annotation i get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: More questions: where does `poi` in the initializer come from? How is `selectedPoi` defined?

Comment: Sorry for they delay, selectedPoi is a property of the controller

Comment: Getting the same thing, only in iOS simulator though.

Comment: Try using `as?` instead of `as` and `annotation!.poi` instead of `annotation.poi`.  You may also want to check the annotation type first (e.g. `if annotation is PoiAnnotation`).

Comment: Hi @Jozef, did you get any solution regarding this issue? I've got the exact same situation and got stuck.

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca If i remember correctly it went away with a newer version of Xcode 6 beta or at least there is code completion to help you fix it in later betas.

Comment: Wow, you know what @Jozef? Following your comment, I simply moved the member on a line below (switching 2 members) and the app runs, no more EXC_BAD_ACCESS!

Answer (score 2):

This EXC_BAD_ACCESS error and the 'only on simulator' symptom can usually be cleared up with a project clean.

Try 'Product - Clean' Worked for me.